# PostgreSQL, using XML with LIKE and DISTINCT

Tags: postgresql

After starting with XML columns as holders for key/value type of data I would like to know if PostgreSQL 'LIKE' and 'DISTINCT' could be used in such data what are my needs.

In previous question I post [example table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410412/postgresql-using-xml) which covers needs of those topic too.

So, such query...

```
SELECT myindex, xpath('/setup/node()/text()', description) FROM temp1
```

gives wanted results by extracting all data from all nodes of stored XML's.

```
"{mydatabase,127.0.0.1,john,4424}"
"{herdatabase,127.0.0.1,saly,5432}"
```

Now I am try to filter results by value on key :

```
SELECT myindex, xpath('/setup/node()/text()', description) FROM temp1 
   WHERE (xpath('/setup/DBUSER/text()', description))::TEXT[] = '{saly}'::TEXT[];
```

And get expected result:

```
"{herdatabase,127.0.0.1,saly,5432}"
```

1) Here is problem that I don't know how to use LIKE instead of '='.

```
SELECT myindex, xpath('/setup/node()/text()', description) FROM temp1 
   WHERE (xpath('/setup/DBUSER/text()', description))::TEXT[] LIKE 'aly'::TEXT[];
```

2) Better to say I would like that my 'LIKE' search under all usable data, like this:

```
SELECT myindex, xpath('/setup/node()/text()', description) FROM temp1 
   WHERE (xpath('/setup/node()/text()', description))::TEXT[] LIKE 'aly'::TEXT[];
```

But that also don't work.

3) And to be more precise in real world here is need to filter usable data from XML with DISTINCT criteria since there will be a same data more times. Like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT xpath('/setup/node()/text()', description) FROM temp1 
   WHERE (xpath('/setup/node()/text()', description))::TEXT[] LIKE 'aly'::TEXT[];
```

I have described functionality now but with messy data and text column type and to get more organized data I would like to switch to XML.

Please help to get answers as needed.

**EDIT**
Postgres 9.3, windows 7.
Data for this is here: [PostgreSQL, using xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410412/postgresql-using-xml)

This is my query:

```
SELECT LAST(myindex), LAST(description), content::text, LAST(content)
  FROM (SELECT myindex, description, 
       (xpath('/setup/node()/text()', description)) AS content FROM temp1) AS alias
 WHERE content::text ILIKE '%127%'
 GROUP BY content::text;
```

By trying to make query by myself I see that is better to use group by than distinct.
It is a bit slow but workable.
And some experience thought, is those query OK?

Comment: Some sample data to go with the queries would be nice. Also, what's your PostgreSQL version? (Ever consider setting a non-randomly-generated username?)

Comment: That is my traditional user name with which I am connected emotively :) Of course I gave link to sample data with hope this is clear. Link points to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410412/postgresql-using-xml. In meantime I solved most of problems and only one remain. Please see EDIT in question.

Comment: Since morning is smarter than evening I solve last remaining issue and now I need only to know if is my query OK or can be written better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNNEST()` to split the XML array in your sub-query into rows and then check those values using ILIKE.

```
SELECT myindex, description, content
FROM (
    SELECT myindex, description, UNNEST(xpath('/setup/node()/text()', description))::TEXT AS content
    FROM temp1
    ) AS alias
WHERE content ILIKE '%127%'
```

I haven't benchmarked it, but performance should be better.

Comment: This is also interesting and workable approach, thanks.

Comment: Actually, that will list all DISTINCT rows, but never mind, with use of custom aggreate 'LAST' and GROUP BY I already solved that.